# How to Allow bots only on main page

Tags: robots.txt

I'm trying to create a robots.txt file that allows bots to access ONLY the home page and no other page. Below is the content of the robots.txt file based on the research I have done.

Is this correct?

```
user-agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Why allow bots only on the main page?  Most sites get the majority of their search engine traffic to deep URLs.  Preventing search engine bots from crawling deep pages may significantly hurt your SEO.

Comment: Thanks. Yes its something to reconsider. My website is mainly a listings website for a niche product so the pages other than than the home page are the categories and the individual listings pages.

Comment: I would want to have pages like that indexed in search engines if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for advise. Why is that? just to increase surface area?

Comment: Essentially yes.  Search engines index content.  Your home page is going to contain less than 1% of the content on your site.  Your home page will rank for searches for your brand name, but your deep pages will rank for people searching for the particular products you are selling or product categories.  Ranking for that type of query is very lucrative compared to brand traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question... yes, these `robots.txt` directives would do as you are asking. Blocking everything except the root directory. It is correct to have the `Allow` directive first for the few crawlers that use a first-match policy (as opposed to longest match).

The easiest way to test this is to use [Google's own robots.txt tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en):

Root directory is "allowed":

[image: Root directory is allowed in Google's robots.txt tester]

Everything else is "blocked":

[image: Everything else is blocked in Google's robots.txt tester]

However, whether you should be doing this or not is another matter. From the discussion in comments, it sounds as if these "other" pages form part of your *content* and should be crawlable (and indexed) by search engines after all. (?)